# Calling an async method

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm new to using async methods and could use some help.  Winforms .Net 4.5 program: ReadInputFile loops through each line in a csv file and calls the async method UpdatePOS_Monitor which posts to the API.  Everything is working so far (my database is getting the new rows) but I don't know how to exit the application when ReadInputFile is done because it is calling an async method.  Or if ReadInputFile will get ahead of itself with this setup?  I'm guessing I need to be 'awaiting' somewhere but don't know what to do?  Thank you.

```
    private void ReadInputFile()
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(FilePath + @"\" + FileNameAdd));

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            var Newline = new RevenueLine();
            Newline.ClubID = values[0];
            Newline.Date = values[1];
            Newline.Department = values[2];
            Newline.Description = values[3];
            Newline.Chits = Convert.ToInt32(values[4]);
            Newline.Sales = values[5];                

            UpdatePOS_Monitor(Newline);
        }

    }


    private async void UpdatePOS_Monitor(RevenueLine line)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        try
        {   
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(line);
            HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = await client.PostAsync(API_Address, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `async/await`, the whole chain of methods has to be `async`, all the way down to the root (e.g., to the UI control event handler). In your case it means that `ReadInputFile` has to be `async`, and `UpdatePOS_Monitor` has to be `async Task` rather than `async void`:

```
// root event handler
private async void button_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    await ReadInputFile();
}

private async Task ReadInputFile()
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(FilePath + @"\" + FileNameAdd));

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        var values = line.Split(',');

        var Newline = new RevenueLine();
        Newline.ClubID = values[0];
        Newline.Date = values[1];
        Newline.Department = values[2];
        Newline.Description = values[3];
        Newline.Chits = Convert.ToInt32(values[4]);
        Newline.Sales = values[5];                

        await UpdatePOS_Monitor(Newline);
    }
}

private async Task UpdatePOS_Monitor(RevenueLine line)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(line);
        HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = await client.PostAsync(API_Address, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    }
}
```

Note also `await reader.ReadLineAsync`, `await UpdatePOS_Monitor(Newline)` and the removal of `catch {}` inside `UpdatePOS_Monitor` (it's almost always a bad idea to swallow exceptions like that).